"Type Error: arguement of type 'method' is not iterabe" while initializing SQLAlchemy ORM Object
I have a SQLAlchemy ORM with SqlAlchemy 2.0 using mapped_column() and Deklarative Base. My App starts with falcon and gunicorn in my PyCharm venv with Python3.12.
The database-tables are created correct with   models.Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
I have a PostgresDB and all Tables with their columns are created correctly, also manually creating an Entry is working fine.
But creating an Entry using SQLAlchemy Object init fails, with an Error I don't understand.
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
pass

class VirtualMachine(Base):
__tablename__ = "virtual_machine"

    vm_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    object_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    
    def __init__(self, object_name: str):
        self.vm_id = 1
        self.object_name = object_name

    def __repr__(self):
        pass

    def __dict__(self):
        pass

It's not my first time using SQLAlchemy ORM for Database management,
but I don't get a clue what this Error message means while trying to create an Object 'VirtualMachine' in my unittests.
class TestVM(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.data = {
          "object_name": "test-vm"
        }
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connect_str)
    self.db = engine.connect()

    def test_create_vm(self):
        self.test_vm = VirtualMachine(**self.data)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/api/tests/orm_test/vm_object_test.py", line 51, in test_create_vm
    self.test_vm = VirtualMachine(**self.data)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/api/venv/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 571, in _initialize_instance
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/api/venv/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/api/venv/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 569, in _initialize_instance
    manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/api/src/database/models.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.vm_id = 1
    ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/api/venv/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 537, in __set__
    self.impl.set(
  File "/api/venv/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1272, in set
    old = self.get(state, dict_, PASSIVE_RETURN_NO_VALUE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "api/venv/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1074, in get
    if self.key in dict_:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable

Any one have an idea why it can't be initialized correctly?
I also tried with other datatypes, because in the beginnig I had uuid.UUID as Mapped[type]
and I had asyncio integrated which I now keep out everywhere and startet a wsgi app now.
I thought it might be a problem with the session, but I think it isn't.

What exactly in self.data?

I edited the qestion and added self.data definition. But it is not relevant, because the Error is thrown by the init() where id is set to an int, and the integer does not come from the call of init with VirtualMachine()

Don`t you worry, that init method is overrided? first of all just try to use this init method like
def __init__(...):
    self.obj_name = name
    super().__init__()

or try to realize do you really need this init method in your declarative base

thank you, for that hint!
here is the doc from sql alchemy on that, and it should work without super().init() because it says that "A class that includes an explicit init() method will maintain that method, and no default constructor will be applied." So I don't think I need the default constructor. And I tried it nevertheless, but got the same TypeError.

I can't reproduce this. Is the code in the question a complete [mre]? That is, you can run it outside of the context of your application and the error is reproduced?

I found the Problem and solved it:
I had defined an empty method __dict__(self) this was called instead of default __dict__ function from DeklarativeBase Class.
It is possible to override that methods but it will break into that Error of the Question with empty functions.
Thank you @jabajke for your good hint. And all other for your interest in my topic!

Overriding __dict__ is very risky in Python - you should only do so if you really know what you are doing. There is almost always a better way to achieve your goal.
